# Create template files for specific branch in Synapse

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I need to create a [custom parameters file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/cicd/continuous-integration-delivery#create-custom-parameters-in-the-workspace-template) for the Synapse template export. However I don't want to merge the file to the collaboration branch until I know it works as expected.

Is there a way to create the template files locally using Azure CLI or Powershell? Either from a feature branch or just from a local `template-parameters-definition.json`.

I think that it should be possible because the [Synapse workspace deployment task V2](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AzureSynapseWorkspace.synapsecicd-deploy&ssr=false#review-details) can deploy from a feature branch. I don't want to deploy (yet), I just want to check the template files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not locally, but the mentioned Synapse workspace deployment task can be used to create template files without deployment. This is not really made clear in the documentation.

I'm looking forward to answers which don't require me to run the pipeline, but at least this does not require a merge.

```yaml
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: Synapse workspace deployment@2
  continueOnError: true    
  inputs:
    operation: 'validate'
    ArtifactsFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/mycustomrootfolder'
    TargetWorkspaceName: 'synw-demodeployment-replaceme'
    Environment: 'prod'
    npmpackage: 'prod'
```

[image: Artifacts]

[image]